# How to standardize training set with mu and sigma?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a training set x_train that looks like this:

```
x_train
tensor([[68.0000,  2.0000, 27.5000,  ...,  5.0000,  4.9416, 91.0000],
        [46.0000,  2.0000, 24.7000,  ...,  6.0000,  4.6444, 96.0000],
        [50.0000,  1.0000, 31.0000,  ...,  4.0000,  4.8283, 88.0000],
        ...,
        [57.0000,  1.0000, 24.5000,  ...,  3.0000,  4.5218, 91.0000],
        [45.0000,  1.0000, 24.2000,  ...,  4.0000,  4.2195, 82.0000],
        [23.0000,  1.0000, 29.0000,  ...,  3.0000,  4.5850, 91.0000]])
```

and I'd like to standardize this using the z-score formula z<sub>i</sub> = (x<sub>i</sub> - mu) / sigma, where mu is mean and sigma is standard deviation.

I have tried it as follows (please note I'm only allowed to add code below the ###comments, nowhere else):

```
def norm_set(x: torch.Tensor, mu: torch.Tensor, sigma: torch.Tensor) -> torch.tensor:
  ### your code here

  mu = sum(x) / float(len(x))
  diff = [i - mu for i in x]
  variance = sum([diff[i] ** 2 for i in range(len(diff))]) / len(diff)
  sigma = variance ** 0.5

  # will add loop to calculate z-score here

  return 

###your code here
## normalize x_train and x_test below
norm_set(x_train, mu, sigma)
```

I know that I'll need to loop through all the arrays within the tensor to standardize each value, but my question is how do I pass in the value of mu and sigma at the end when I need to use the function? Wouldn't I need to calculate those values before defining the function itself? Or is there a way to calculate them within the function definition itself? Or do I just put mu = 0 and sigma = 1?

Comment: Why is mu and sigma a parameter to the function if you're going to calculate it from x?

Comment: Also, [torch.mean()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html) and [torch.std()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.std.html) are likely faster ways to calculate mean and standard deviation.

Comment: thanks Nick, I'll use those torch functions. As for why mu and sigma are parameters, I was confused about that too but that it just how the code skeleton was presented, I was only allowed to fill in the method body